# on press button mass stay the color

Tags: android

Hi can some one please help me with this code

```
horse_btn_a1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      horse_btn_a1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("@drawable/ront2"));
    }
});
```

and what I wanna do is when the button is pressed it must stay that color.

Answer (score 0):

Hee, use hex color "#ffffff" with parseColor
    horse_btn_a1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

Hope I help

Comment: hey yes i dit  that but you see my button is round if i use the code like that its not giving me a round button

Answer (score 0):

The [parseColor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor(java.lang.String)) method takes a String, sure, but not a resource string.

You first need to fetch your resource String, then parse that:

Define your color resource like this

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorA">#FF00FF</color>
</resources>
```

Then use it in Java like this:

```
String colorString = getContext().getResources().getString(R.color.colorA);

Color c = Color.parseColor(colorString);

btn.setBackgroundColor(c);
```

Comment: hey i have a round button that is green and when its press it need's to be a round orange button and when you press it need to be a round green button.

Comment: So you mean, the button will be two different colors? One at rest, and another while actively pressed?

Comment: yes, that is correct, the button at rest is green, but when selected the button must change to orange, and when selected again then back to green. It to identify the user what option he has made and if he whats to change his option he can then just select it again to unchecked it. Hope i make sense :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have different drawables based on different states (pressed/disabled/focused) for the same view. Take a look at

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_sel" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_sel" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_unsel" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve like this

red_circle_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">

            <solid android:color="#F00"/>

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

green_circle_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">

            <solid android:color="#0F0"/>

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

blue_circle_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">

            <solid android:color="#00F"/>

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

button_bg.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <item android:drawable="@drawable/red_circle_bg" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/green_circle_bg" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/blue_circle_bg"/>

</selector>
```

In your layout, you can give like this

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/my_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg" />
```

We should do this logic to make it work

```
private boolean mIsSelected = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button horse_btn_a1 = findViewById(R.id.button);

    horse_btn_a1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            horse_btn_a1.setSelected(!mIsSelected);

            mIsSelected = !mIsSelected;
        }
    });
}
```

or we should use [Checkable Button](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Checkable.html)

Comment: hey thanks for the help but the code is not keeping the color it keeps on going back to the blue

Comment: private boolean mIsSelected = false;

        final horse_btn_a1 = findViewById(R.id.horse_btn_a1);

        horse_btn_a1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                horse_btn_a1.setSelected(!mIsSelected);

                mIsSelected = !mIsSelected;
            }
        });
    }
}

Comment: its saying unknown class and it can not

Comment: Could you please update your layout file in question.

Comment: you can add you layout in the question.